# PHP get environment variables from system then from .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, environment-variables

I have set environment variable in:

1. System (Windows 7, apache)

   ```
   ENVIRONMENT = localhost
   ```
2. *.htaccess* file

   ```
   SetEnv ENVIRONMENT localhost
   ```

Now in my php code I get this variable with function `getenv()`.

```
$environment = getenv('ENVIRONMENT');
```

**Question:**

**How to get variable from system first, if it is not set, then get variable from .htaccess**

Comment: _“This house originally had a red door, but now it has been replaced with a blue one – so how can I now take a photo of it that still shows the old red door?”_ – you can’t, of course.

Comment: `SetEnv` is actually the _same thing_ as setting a system env var. The difference is that you set it with a specific value that only applies to the environment in which apache runs. You can define the `ENVIRONMENT` variable with any value you like, as long as apache is running in a different environment, it doesn't matter. So when you say "get the var from system", you seem to mean "get it from env X first, then from the apache env" which makes no sense at all

Answer (score 1):

As i know you can't htaccess overwriting all, only the option is take that ENVIRONMENT var in other php script where that htaccess not have any influence and store it in session lets say and the overwrite by session(if it presetn) $environment variable